# Laravel 6 PHP unit testing - Session store not set on request

Tags: php, laravel

I got a run time error (RuntimeException: Session store not set on request.) while running the unit testing

```
public function testUserCanLoginCorrectCredentials()
{
    $this->withoutExceptionHandling();
    $user = factory(Users::class)->create();
    $response = $this->post('/admin/login', [
        'email' => $user->email,
        'password' => '123456789',
    ]);
    $response->withSession(['user_id' => $user->id]);
    $response->assertRedirect('/admin/dashboard');
    $this->assertAuthenticatedAs($user);
}
```

In Controller :

```
$checkUserExist =$this->users->where('email',$request->email)->where('password',$request->password)->first();
if(isset($checkUserExist)){

    $user = Auth::guard('users');
    $users = Auth::login($checkUserExist);
    //Authentication passed...
    $request->session()->put('admin_user_id', $checkUserExist->id);
    return redirect('admin/dashboard')->with('success', 'You are Logged in !');
} else {
    return redirect('/admin')->with('error','Invalid Password, Please Entered Correct Credentials!');
}
```

While running the command I'm getting this error

```
Time: 1.76 seconds, Memory: 52.00 MB

There was 1 error:

1) Tests\Unit\HostLoginTest::testUserCanLoginCorrectCredentials
RuntimeException: Session store not set on request.

C:\xampp\htdocs\parkk-web\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Http\Request.php:482
C:\xampp\htdocs\parkk-web\app\Http\Controllers\Auth\LoginController.php:107
C:\xampp\htdocs\parkk-web\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Routing\Controller.php:54
C:\xampp\htdocs\parkk-web\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Routing\ControllerDispatcher.php:45
C:\xampp\htdocs\parkk-web\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Routing\Route.php:219
C:\xampp\htdocs\parkk-web\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Routing\Route.php:176
C:\xampp\htdocs\parkk-web\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Routing\Router.php:680
```

Comment: This seems more like an integration test, not a unit test.

Comment: `withSession` is meant to be set on the request not the response i.e. put it before `->post`.

Answer (score 0):

It seems like your session is not found in the request. The most probable cause of this is not using the  `Illuminate\Session\Middleware\StartSession::class` middleware in your Kernal which is responsible for starting the session.

I would also suggest not storing the user password directly in the database, but rather it should be hashed and checked when logging in.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of:

```
$request->session()->put('admin_user_id', $checkUserExist->id);
```

Try:

```
session()->put('admin_user_id', $checkUserExist->id);
```